# Getting JSON undefined after jQuery parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

Here's a sample of the JSON string :

```
    {
      "table": {
         "tfoot": "Footer",
         "tr0": [
                  {
                  "form": "formData",
                  "td": "Content"
                  }
                ]
       }
     }
```

And the jQuery code I'm using to parse it :

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: source, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 

            $.each(data, function() {
              $.each(this, function(key, value) {
                switch (key) {
                    case "tfoot":
                        alert(value) // access to this node works fine                      
                    break;

                    default: 
                        alert(value.td) // this is undefined
                    break;
                }       
              });
            });
        }
    });
```

I tried a Console.log with Chrome and I can see every nodes and the data is okay. Anyone have a clue how I can access the "form" or "td" nodes?

Comment: [] tags representing its an array. So you should have another loop for tr0 or just use tr0[0].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5514133/1288 http://stackoverflow.com/a/13586208/1288

Answer (score 1):

The object value is an array, so you can not access the td property of it. If you wanted to get to the first item in the arrays td property you would need to do:

```
value[0].td
```

full code:

```
$.each(t, function() {
  $.each(this, function(key, value) {
    switch (key) {
      case "tfoot":
        console.log(value) // access to this node works fine                      
      break;

      default: 
        console.log(value[0].td) // this now prints "Content"
      break;
    }       
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

value.table.tr0[0].td

Is what u are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in json { } defines an json object, [ ] defines an json Array.

So since after `"tr0"` comes a [ ] (array) you need to access it with an index.
`value.table.tr0[0].td` should work